# Informal way of saying "moreover"

Tags: single-word-requests, discourse-markers

> My teachers said that they couldn't do anything for me. That no matter
>   how many times they added and rounded up my scores, the result was
>   still zero. **Moreover**, if they let me pass the other students would protest
>   . They would consider it unfair.

Not sure if I'm mistaken but I think *moreover* has a more formal overtone. What's a more informal option?

Comment: How about "besides"?

Comment: **, and** *if they did let me pass **,** the other students would protest.*

Comment: Have you looked up the synonyms for this discourse marker?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Yes, but no one seemed to fit.

Comment: "In addition" is an option, but "besides" is probably better.

Comment: "Also, ......."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one that's quite casual:

- Plus, if they let me pass,...

Comment: Note the change of verb tacitly made here: teachers don't _make_ you (= force you to) pass, they _let_ you (= allow you to) pass.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You're right. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

"Additionally" would work.

Personally, I would only use "moreover" when I want to say "Additionally and more importantly", but according to [the dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/moreover?s=t) I've made up the "more importantly" bit myself.

Comment: Moreover, I would use additionally exactly as you describe.

Comment: What about-  Also, if they let me pass,...

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, *moreover* sits nicely in that paragraph quoted.

An idiomatic expression with the same meaning might be [***to boot***](http://grammarist.com/usage/to-boot/): 'as well', 'in addition'. Descended from OE *bōt* ‘advantage, remedy’. See also the post [Why do we say “to boot”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9538/why-do-we-say-to-boot) here at EL&U.

Comment: _To boot_ sounds archaic, which I'd say is worse than 'formal' in informal contexts.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Could you substantiate the _archaic_ claim?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth True, it is not so frequent. I absolutely do not dispute that. I only now realize what you might mean by archaic, perhaps -- that the usage is declining (or perhaps only slightly, because it might never have been used frequently). But in the linked post, for example, the usage is quite colloquial. And the formulation I actually had in mind was "To boot, if they let me pass, the other students would protest."

Comment: I can show Google Ngrams comparing their estimated frequencies of use of _too_, _also_, and _as well_, with 'to boot' almost flatlining. But I wouldn't know how to discount the many false positives that appear. It certainly sounds weird to me in 'If they let me pass, the other students would protest, to boot.'  CDO has 'old fashioned'. As I say, _to me_ it sounds closer to one degree further along the line. And OP is after a conversational register here.

Comment: The fact that we have to have a link that explains _to boot_ seems enough of a reason to not use it casually.

Comment: @JohnathanElmore The link is a courtesy to the reader, as are the definitions and references I give. The fact that I provide links to other posts and resources should not be mistaken for a hint that I or the readers of my post might not be familiar with the idiom. I.a., you will find that it is used _very_ casually in the linked post.

Comment: I say "to boot", and it's about as far from formal as you can get! Archaic, my foot!

Comment: That's true, @anemone.  I just think that the phrase is useful only if the listener is used to it.  I think of a boot.  Then I think of "kicking".  Then I think of the context it's used in and realize, "oh, you mean 'as well'".  Then I think, "I will never use that word."

Comment: @JohnathanElmore Yes, I agree, it is somewhat unusual. Also iconic -- exactly as you say, it captures your whole attention with its sound alone, it is distracting and dramatic. Maybe not _quite_ what the OP was looking for. Actually, I quite like "Plus, ...". Still, I think "To boot,..." is applicable here depending on how much emphasis one wants to give to the phrase following it.

Answer (score 0):

"Besides" would be a good substitute.